# jQuery- how to execute toggle after element is checked

Tags: jquery, list, toggle

I creates a toggle list view. I have to close the list after the user click on some element in the list and this item is signed by a check icon. The problem that the list is toggle before I see the check icon on the chosen element

```
$('[data-postas]').click(function changeHeader(event){
        var element = $(event.srcElement);
        $('.toggle-post').text(element.text());
        $('#postAs').val(element.attr('data-postas'));
        if(element.attr('data-company')){
                $('#company').val(element.attr('data-company'));

        }
        $('.icon-cheack').remove();
        element.append('<i class="icon-cheack fright"></i>');
        $(".ul-post").toggle();

        })

        $(".toggle-post").click(function(){
    $(".ul-post").toggle();
  });
```

Comment: can you please create a fiddle, where the described behavior is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A jsfiddle would certainly help your question, but as I understand it, you're having a problem where the listbox is closing before the check animation has completed, correct? This sounds like a perfect use-case for [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout).

```
$('[data-postas]').click(function changeHeader(event){
    var element = $(event.srcElement);
    $('.toggle-post').text(element.text());
    $('#postAs').val(element.attr('data-postas'));
    if(element.attr('data-company')) {
          $('#company').val(element.attr('data-company'));
    }
    $('.icon-cheack').remove();
    element.append('<i class="icon-cheack fright"></i>');

    // Note the timeout for 1000ms (1s) to collapse the list.
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".ul-post").toggle();
    }, 1000);
})

$(".toggle-post").click(function(){
    $(".ul-post").toggle();
});
```

The extra `setTimeout` I've added should delay the listbox from collapsing till 1s after the initial click.

Check out the [MDN docs for `setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) for more information.

Comment: thanks! Though don't the append have to be some delay?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand your code well enough to say. I'm not sure why you're appending an italics class with no text in it. But I don't think you want anything else to happen inside that setTimeout, right when the list is collapsed. Perhaps you want another setTimeout with a shorter duration to achieve your goal?

Comment: The italics class is inside a div which has text. I decrease the time of the setTimeout. I just don't understand why I needed the delay if the toggle() is called after the append (I assumed that there is tiny delay....)